# Develop app with corona and add this in existing android native app

Tags: android, ios, coronasdk, native-code

I have requirement that I have to develop an app using Corona SDK and then add this app as a feature to existing Android and iOS applications. Means there are two existing apps for Android and iOS. I have to add actually a game feature. I have heard about Corona that it is cross platform SDK. So I decided to create in Corona and then add its source to Android and iOS apps. I want to ask is it possible? Does corona provides the feature to generate Native code for Android and iOS platforms?

Comment: according to the official corona websiet [link]http://www.coronalabs.com/ it doesn't support cross planform development. There are others (Mono for instance). There are different levels of what "Cross Platform" means (like Mono doesn't do cross platform GUI from what I can tell)

Comment: why don't you use cocos2d-x? free and crossplatform.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nope, corona build process is closed from you. You wont get any native sources of your app, you will get a compiled standalone application for platform you asked build for.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using Corona Enterprise.

Corona Enterprise makes Corona run as a library for your application, so Corona Enterprise do exactly what you want.

Comment: Means It will create a jar for Android that I can add to my Android project and same for iOS?

Comment: they do not give enterprise version to everyone.

Comment: Leonidos Corona enterprise is more expensive yes, but anyone with enough money can buy it. Maybe Raza client can pay for it.

@Raza, I never used Corona Enterprise, but it works by behaving as a library, you will need to add Corona to your projects (both iOS and Android) and recompile them, then Corona will run whatever main.lua you throw at it (so theoretically you can make a app with several Corona games on it).

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But I think that the question was about common Corona version. Even with enterprise version you can't get native code... but you can add corona game as a part of existing application and you can add some features that sdk misses.

Comment: But that is what the guy wants... add corona game as part of existing application.